# Why does Tor use a new route every few minutes

Tags: anonymity, tor, routing

As far as I know, Tor selects three new nodes every few minutes. What is the advantage of this?

The only thing I came up with was to prevent "Bad exit nodes" from viewing too much of your (hopefully encrypted) traffic. But on the other hand, when using less nodes the chance is smaller to find a evil node at all.

Answer (score 1):

Tor is best known for providing anonymity to the users communication. Every time tor uses different routes to forward the data to destination to maintain anonymity. If it is not doing so then same path can be traced to intercept the communication. I think this is the best method to anonymize the communication.

Comment: "If it is not doing so then same path can be traced to intercept the communication." Any details on this? I mean this basically says Tor can be cracked if you use the same route for more than a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume this is to suppress the amount of intersection attacks(Nodes periodically fail or leave the network; any chain that remains functioning cannot have been routed through either the nodes that left or the nodes that recently joined the network) before/between/after the gaurd, relay and exit nodes. Since if you are able to intersect one and it does not change you will have a open intersection to attack for some time.